# Change CSS for different browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-9, flexbox

I was just wondering if it was possible to change a bit of your CSS if it is being viewed in a different browser.

For example, I'm using this particular CSS for a flexbox div:

```
.wdFlex {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-moz-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-moz-box-pack: justify;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
-webkit-align-content: flex-start;
-ms-flex-line-pack: start;
align-content: flex-start;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-moz-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

It works nice in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE10+ etc., but as you know, IE9 does not support flexbox. Now, I can do the thing flexbox do in normal CSS, but now I just wanna learn some flexbox stuff and try it out. But ofc, IE9 should be supported in my opinion, so my question is, if there is any way, without changing the entire css file via:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

to change the css ?

Just like instead of the flexbox thing in the above CSS, it just wrote out, if IE9:

```
.wdFlex {
display: inline-block;

}
```

As an example.

Hope you understand what I mean :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can only be done using Javascipt. Its not possible using HTML or CSS.

Comment: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of CSS cascading, so if the property is not supported in the browser you can write a fallback.

```
.wdflex {
    display: inline-block; /* for IE9 */
    display: flex-box; /* browsers that support it will pick it up */
}
```

For this particular example you could use conditional comments to apply browser specific classes to the html tag in the markup like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 10]><!--> <html class="ie10"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Obviously can write more classes and do more complicated things with this, but you get the idea. Then just write the css on the class.
This post goes into more detail about this technique and specifically handling display: flex
http://designkarma.co.uk/blog/using-flexbox-now